# What is the best practice to use ExtJS with Django Framework

Tags: django, extjs

I like to use django in the server side with extjs in the client.
Possibly using a REST interface for publishing the resources.
Ideas about that?
thanks.

Comment: You should try [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider [django-rest-interface](http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/).

Answer (score 3):

Probably your should update your question with extjs version. Current extjs version 4.2 can be nicely integrated with django. One of the examples:  https://github.com/linovia/django-rest-framework-extjs

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs 3 now use REST intensively !